# How do steady clocks interact with limited-bit time representations?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

20.11.7.2/1 begins:

> Objects of class `steady_clock` 
>   represent clocks for which values of `time_point` never decrease as
>   physical time advances and for which values of `time_point` advance at a
>   steady rate relative to real time. That is, the clock may not be
>   adjusted.

In concept, this is lovely, but given that there will almost certainly be a limited number of bits to represent a point in time, it's hard to imagine an implementation where a steady clock's value just keeps increasing forever.

20.11.3/2 seems to back up my lack of imagination, because it refers (in a non-normative note) to a clock "wrapping around." This suggests that if I have a `time_point t1` and a later `time_point t2` taken from the same steady clock, `t2` could appear to come earlier in time, because the clock could have wrapped between `t1` and `t2`.

I find it very difficult to make sense of the Standard in this area. Can somebody lend clarity regarding the relationship and interaction of a steady clock and clock wrapping?

Answer (score 3):

Please submit a bug report when you actually witness the `steady_clock` roll over.  On my system, if I don't reboot my computer for the next 292 years, that will happen in the year 2305.  Sorry if I don't respond at that time. :-)

Kidding around aside, the implementation is required to support a sufficiently large bit length such that a clock roll over can not be observed during a practical duration of time.  Counting nanoseconds in a 64 bit integer from the time of computer boot is one reasonable implementation of this.

Comment: Is there something in the Standard that sets a minimum amount of time that a steady clock runs before wrapping? On a machine with 16-bit words, could a steady clock use a 16-bit representation for, say, millisconds?

Comment: I do not believe so.  When first proposed, `steady_clock` (then named `monotonic_clock`) was not even required to be supported by all platforms.  It was "conditionally supported".  But the committee decided to mandate its support.  Also mandated is a long long type with at least 64 bits.  So presumably, if a machine can support a long long, it can support a `steady_clock::rep` which is 64 bits, even if the underlying tick counter is 16 bits.  The bit length of `steady_clock::rep` isn't mandated per-say, it is just required to never decrease.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe - if it was allowed to run incorrectly after a certain amount of time it wouldn't be a steady clock.